# How to log user into Superset UI

Tags: django, python-requests, apache-superset

I'm using Django and superset. I'm able to login programmatically in one of my views and get an access token and a csrf token with my username and password. However, my end goal is to log the user into an embedded superset dashboard in one of my templates. In my view I'm using request sessions and I can see my cookie session value. In my UI, the cookie that is set is a different value.

Is there a way that I can tell Django to use the same request session in my template as what is being used in my view?

Or, perhaps there is another way to accomplish the same task of logging a user into the UI automatically. I'm open to that too, it just seems like I'm so close. The code I'm using is below, specifically the programmatic_login function. It all works, I would just like to let my template know that the user has already been authenticated.

```
class SuperSetApi():
csrf_token = ''
access_token = ''
refresh_token = ''
session = None
base_url = 'http://superset:8088/'
username = ''
password = ''
guest_token = ''
custom_token = ''


def url(self, base_url, url_path):
    return base_url + url_path


def add_remote_user_header(self, username, url):
    session = requests.Session()
    self.username = username
    # url = 'http://superset:8088/superset/explore_json/?form_data={"slice_id":1,"viz_type":"table","datasource":"1__table","url_params":{},"time_range":"No+filter"}'
    # url = 'http://localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/1/?standalone=0&show_filters=0&expand_filters=0&logme=user2'
    session.headers['X-PROXY-REMOTE-USER']= username
    # url = 'http://superset:8088/superset/welcome?logme=user1'
    response = session.get(url)
    # session = requests.Session()
    # self.session = session
    # session.headers['X-PROXY-REMOTE-USER'] = username
    # response = session.get(url)
    print(response)
    # print(response.json())
    return session


def get_access_token(self, username, password):
    session = requests.Session()
    self.username = username
    self.password = password

    response = session.post(
        self.url(self.base_url, 'api/v1/security/login'),
        json={
            "username": self.username,
            "password": self.password,
            "provider": "db",
            "refresh": "true",
        },
    )
    access_token = response.json()['access_token']
    self.access_token = access_token
    refresh_token = response.json()['refresh_token']
    self.refresh_token = refresh_token
    session.headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {self.access_token}'
    self.session = session
    print(f'access_token: {access_token}')


def get_csrf_token(self):
    session = self.session
    response = session.get(self.url(self.base_url, 'api/v1/security/csrf_token/'))
    csrf_token = response.json()['result']
    self.csrf_token = csrf_token
    session.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = self.csrf_token
    self.session = session
    print(f'csrf_token: {csrf_token}')


def get_embedded_dashboard(self, dashboard_id=1):
    session = self.session
    session.headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {self.access_token}'
    response = session.get(self.url(self.base_url, f'api/v1/dashboard/{dashboard_id}/embedded'))
    dashboard_uuid = response.json()['result']['uuid']
    print(f'dashboard_uuid: {dashboard_uuid}')
    return dashboard_uuid


def programmatic_login(self, username, password):
    self.get_access_token(username, password)
    self.get_csrf_token()
    response = self.session.post(self.url(self.base_url, '/login/'), data={
    'username': self.username,
    'password': self.password,
    'csrf_token':self.csrf_token
    })
    print(self.session)
    print(self.session.cookies)
    print(response)
    # print(response.text)
    print(response.cookies)
    return self.session

def get_guest_token(self, guest_token_payload):
    session = self.session
    
    # the crucial part: add the specific auth-header for the python call
    
    response = session.post(self.url(self.base_url, 'api/v1/security/guest_token/') , json=guest_token_payload)
    guest_token = response.json()['token']
    self.guest_token = guest_token
    self.session = session
    print(f'guest_token: {guest_token}')
```

relevant portion of my template is:

```
<div class="row-container" allow="fullscreen" style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100vh; flex-direction: column; overflow: visible;">
<iframe src="http://localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/1/?standalone=0&show_filters=0&expand_filters=0" allow="fullscreen" style="flex-grow: 1; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100vh;"></iframe>
```